# Good practice for helper functions in Django views

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on a project in Django. On my `views.py` I need to make use of multiple helper functions. In order to keep my code clean, I am going to create another file to wrap all these functions. I was planning to call the file just `functions.py` or `helpers.py`.

**Which is the good practice to add helper functions for Django views?** Is there any kind of convention, rule or anything?

**UPDATE:** These functions are closely related to the app itself. They have no sense out of their app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be to create multiple files with only functions related to each other. Ideally, if they are app-agnostic, put them in a python package outside of the django app you are using.

Ie. 
All functions related to users go to `view_helpers/users.py`,
All function related to json go to `view_helpers/json.py`

The directory structure would be like that

```
django_project/
    main_django_app/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        settings.py
        ...
    view_helpers/
        __init__.py
        json.py
    manage.py
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that those functions are closely related to the app itself. They have no sense out of the app. I will update the question. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I would use the same approach, just put the view_helpers package inside the app package